# MaterialStateTextStyle.resolveWith doesn't work in TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart, themes

I have a `TextFormField` with the style:

```dart
TextFormField(
  initialValue: 'test',
  enabled: false,
  style: MaterialStateTextStyle.resolveWith(
    (Set<MaterialState> states) {
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
        return const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.blue,
        );
      }
      return const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.lime,
      );
    },
  ),
  // ...
)
```

And global Theme:

```dart
ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  disabledColor: Colors.grey,
  // ...
)
```

Styles in TextFormField are ignoring (text `test` is grey). Why?

If I do this:

```dart
TextFormField(
  initialValue: 'test',
  enabled: false,
  style: const TextStyle(
    color: Colors.purple,
  ),
  // ...
)
```

The text `test` is purple.